# join() fails if io_context.run() is called inside the thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm getting this error (and a similar "Resource deadlock avoided" error if I use std::thread):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >'
  what():  boost thread: trying joining itself: Resource deadlock avoided
```

Here's the darn code that's causing it. *The exception happens when join() is called.*

```
TCPClient::TCPClient(string EOM_delimiter) 
{
    EOM_delimiter_ = EOM_delimiter;
    socket_ = make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(io_context_);

    io_context_thread_ = make_unique<boost::thread>([this]()
        { 
        boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> fake_work = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io_context_);
        io_context_.run(); 
        });
}

bool TCPClient::disconnect()
{
    boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    socket_->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
    socket_->close(ignored_ec);

    io_context_.stop();
    while (!io_context_.stopped()) { continue; }

    io_context_thread_->join(); //this is where the error happens

    return true;
}
```

Lastly, here's the calling circumstance:

```
TCPClient tcp_client("\n");
//sending and receiving work fine in between..
tcp_client.disconnect();
```

I'm confused, as I had thought this sort of deadlocking would only happen if I called join() from the thread itself, or from a handler that it had called. However, that's not what's happening. I noticed that if I don't run io_context from inside the thread, join() works fine.

-Boost v1.66

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you just construct `TCPClient` and then call `disconnect` without any sending or receiving in between?

Comment: Seems to run without getting the exception on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1AKlj0X7idraVYpu).

Comment: Don't call `join` on a service thread (so, don't call `disconnect` there either)

Answer (score 0):

Fudge..I was inadvertently calling disconnect() and therefore join() from a handler. XDDD
Thanks ya'll!